# Unexpected Intent with action WEB_SEARCH

Tags: android, android-intent, android-search

I have pretty large app to inspect with a lot of activities. One of most popular exceptions is

> No Activity found to handle Intent {
>   act=android.intent.action.WEB_SEARCH (has extras) }

What the heck? I don't see in code any "WEB_SEARCH" anywhere, I can't reproduce it, I don't even know where to look for cause (in which `Activity`). Below stack of `Exception`, without any class from my package... How to track and fix this?

```
Fatal Exception: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.WEB_SEARCH (has extras) }
   at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1659)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1434)
   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3432)
   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3393)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(Unknown Source)
   at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3628)
   at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3596)
   at android.webkit.SelectActionModeCallbackSec.onActionItemClicked(SelectActionModeCallbackSec.java:390)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView$ActionModeCallbackWrapper.onActionItemClicked(PhoneWindow.java:3264)
   at android.support.v7.view.SupportActionModeWrapper$CallbackWrapper.onActionItemClicked(Unknown Source)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7$ActionModeCallbackWrapperV7.onActionItemClicked(Unknown Source)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7$ActionModeCallbackWrapperV7.onActionItemClicked(Unknown Source)
   at android.support.v7.view.StandaloneActionMode.onMenuItemSelected(Unknown Source)
   at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(Unknown Source)
   at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(Unknown Source)
   at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(Unknown Source)
   at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.onItemClick(Unknown Source)
   at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:301)
   at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1490)
   at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3275)
   at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:4518)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Comment: Do you have a code like this in your application 
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(Url));
startActivity(i);

Comment: no, I don't, as mentioned in question: _I don't see in code any "WEB_SEARCH" anywhere_ (ctrl+shift+f)

Comment: Well I can suggest that to Use debugging mode when you click on the particular thing and see the step by step process

Comment: good idea! could you point me which "particular thing"? I have over a dozen of (large) Activities, few times more Fragments and probably over hundred layouts/custom widgets, and no info from above stack where its happening. Obviously I cannot reproduce that, catching `ActivityNotFoundException` is easy when you know what is causing it... One and only hint from stack is `onActionItemClicked`, so it must be click on `Toolbar`, but I have custom menu and handled actions everywhere.

Comment: `MenuPopupHelper` and `AbsListView` present in stack also suggest click on position in overflow menu. but all my menus are custom and properly handled. I've tried on few devices long press on text and changing `ActionMode`, which changes Toolbar look and its options/menu, but I don't see any new (not mine) search option. Bug is very rare, but present in variety of devices - different manufacturers, models, OS versions. I don't see any exception from Android 6.0, but probably this version isn't popular enough at this moment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have to answer my own question for another future searchers. For use in `Activity` with `WebView`, or for safety in some `Base`/`MainActivity` abstract layer:

```
@Override
public void startActivityForResult(Intent i, int reqCode, Bundle b){
    boolean activityExists = i.resolveActivityInfo(getPackageManager(), 0) != null;
    if(activityExists)
        super.startActivityForResult(i, reqCode, b);
    else{
        if(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH.equals(i.getAction()) && i.getExtras()!=null){
            String query = i.getExtras().getString(SearchManager.QUERY, null);
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.google.pl/search?q="+query));
            boolean browserExists = i.resolveActivityInfo(getPackageManager(), 0) != null;
            if(browserExists && query!=null){
                startActivity(browserIntent);
                return;
            }
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.error_no_app_for_intent, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Reason of this behaviour is (probably) custom system UI/modded Android made by hardware producer, which is adding some features related with searching. Not reproducable on "clean" Android device

Answer (score 2):

Met the same issue recently, did some dig, i think snachmsm's answer is good, and i wanna make some analysis for other searchers.

Obviously no code written by me is starting an Intent with WEB_SEARCH, and according to the crash log, the intent is invoked by android.webkit.SelectActionModeCallbackSec.onActionItemClicked, so the fact is that if you use a webview, when the user long click and select some text , in some phones or themes or ROMs it will show an ActionMenu with "find" and "web search" or only one of them, depends on the various implementation. And when the user click "web search" it will start an intent with WEB_SEARCH.

Then the solution is simple, in the Activities that use a webview, override startActivityForResult to handle the certain intent. Why don't he override startActivity either? Because startActivity invoke startActivityForResult eventually.